# PHP Variable from DOM Selector .text() won't append to a link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull the text out of a div and then tweet it.  I'm getting the text out using the method below, but when I'm trying to add it to the tweet link below:

```
        <?php 
                    $include = quotescollection_quote();
                    $html = <<<EOF
<div class="quote">

{$include}
                        </div>

EOF;

// create a document object from your html string
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// create a xpath selector for the document
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// use xpath query to access the text of <q> node
$quote = $selector
 ->query('//div[@class="quote"]/div/p/q/text()')
 ->item(0)
 ->nodeValue;
 ?>

 <?php echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Currently reading' . $quote . 'from the Winifred Paper Blog!" title="Click to send this page to Twitter!" target="_blank">Tweet it</a>' ?>
```

Output is currently the contents of the quote variable as text breaking up the link.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show an example the actual output you are getting and the output you would want instead? I can't quite work it out from your description of the problem

Comment: From the example code you showed in [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150579/dom-selector-and-script-for-accessing-text-generated) your code works fine for me - are you certain that `$include` contains what you think it does? Can you show a `var_dump($include);` ?

Comment: Yeah - the var_dump is null.  That's the problem.  I was associating the actual HTML that comes from running that quotescollection_quote() shortcode as the output.  I really just need to find the text in the div after it's shot out of that div.  I'm a total PHP newbie trying to help my wife so sorry, I'm sure there is a simple solution.

Comment: That's actually fairly simple to solve - replace the first line with `ob_start(); quotescollection_quote(); $quote = ob_get_clean();` and it should work as expected. This basically just captures the output created by that function and puts it into the `$quote` variable - see [the output buffering chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) of the manual for more information

Comment: Dave you are an absolute god send.  It's working perfectly now.   I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries :-) - you should know that WP is not by any stretch of the imagination a good usage of PHP, it's possible to write nice, clean, sane-looking code with PHP - but not with WP, it's designed to be as "idiot-proof" as possible, or in other words "to be used by people who don't understand computers". So you'll find a lot of wtf with it.

Comment: Having said that, it [looks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quotes-collection/other_notes/#The-quotescollection_quote()-template-function) like the `quotescollection_quote()` function can be made to return the HTML string instead of outputting it if you pass `'echo=0'` to the first argument, so you can actually avoid the slightly nasty output buffering approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'urlencode' if you having issues with $quote being passed into the URL:

```
 <?php echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Currently reading' . urlencode($quote) . 'from the Winifred Paper Blog!" title="Click to send this page to Twitter!" target="_blank">Tweet it</a>' ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Thanks - it actually appears to be a problem with how my selector is running, not with my encoding.  Trying to work through it - but thank you!